# Password protecting an Application

Tags: macos, mac, applications

I read the Question [Is there a way to password protect individual apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14013/is-there-a-way-to-password-protect-individual-apps) - but the answers focused too much on security issues.

I want to clarify my needs: I use a Software to write my personal diary. I just want to prevent people using my iTunes as a Jukebox and see that interesting icon somewhere and open it.

I don't want to create a special guest account or something like that, and I don't need a mechanism to prevent people from finding my diary files on the filesystem.

I just want to enter a password before the app starts. Is there a freeware solution without using terminal for every launch?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually left up to the writer of the application to make a password work the best. If you forget to close the app or if you put your mac to sleep, any wrapper you construct will likely not secure the diary. Building the password into the app makes it far superior to a gateway app that asks for the password and then launches another app.

That being said, have you investigated these nice journaling software that include the ability to password protect your files?

- [Mac Journal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macjournal/id439930856?mt=12) by [Mariner Software](https://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/)
- [Memories](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memories/id414703286?mt=12) by [Coding Robots](http://www.codingrobots.com/memoires/)
- [Diary](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diary-most-simple-elegant/id403192563?mt=12) by [Michael Gobel](http://cutediaryapp.com/)

There are easily another 10 viable softwares on the App Store alone that serve this exact niche. Also - [this review](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-journal-mac/) seems to cover some other options, but is about 12 months old now.

Comment: Thanks for your advices and your ideas - but in fact, it's not only for the diary. What I'm looking for is a solution like a gateway app that just asks for a password before launching the app, nothing else.