# Password-Protect Apps MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, privacy

I need to block an app with a password for privacy, but I can't find this feature in Screentime.

It used to be in the old Parental controls in Mojave and earlier, but it seems to have been removed in more recent versions.

- free apps preferred

Is there a 3rd party app to block apps with a password?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve here, exactly? What's the purpose of blocking an app with a password, versus allowing or not allowing someone to access to that app at that person's user account level (which is what I think the Big Sur parental controls allow you to do)?

Comment: This is a good (possibly duplicate) software recommendation question. Let’s not argue with the idea that someone wants this. I think the market will speak - free apps means someone else is paying so you may be surprised by what happens to your privacy in those cases. Or anyone can choose software that fits the bill and saves them time if it’s paid. This question is +1 as its clear and practical.

Comment: I’ll try to link to a better solution - [encrypt the data the app uses so you’re actually protected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14048/5472) and not just [putting a gate down that’s not effective](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51423/5472), easily circumvented https://blog.rootshell.be/2013/03/25/are-you-using-nac-like-no-access-control/

Answer (score 2):

From a quick internet search, I found [this article](https://7labs.io/tips-tricks/lock-mac-apps.html) that lists two apps:

- [AppLocker](https://apps.apple.com/app/applocker-password-lock-apps/id1132845904?mt=12) is free to block one app, with a $10 purchase to unlock full functionality. Take this with a grain of salt, though - the average review is one star
- [AppCrypt](https://www.cisdem.com/appcrypt-mac.html) is a one-time $30 payment ([25% off with their coupon code](https://7labs.io/deals/cisdem-appcrypt-discount-coupon.html)). It looks like you can download it for free from their website, but likely has limited functionality